# Pass a uri to AuthenticationContext

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

Hey, sorry for my bad english...

I created a new Silverlight Business Application and all is working fine. I have 2 DomainServices, one expose my database objects and another is the default AuthenticationDomainService. The problem is I have to run this services on a different server than the silverlight application... when I create my DomainContext to query data, I use the constructor that accepts a URI specifying the URI to the server, this works but I do not know how to do it for the AuthenticationContext since it's not me who instantiate it (looks like it is automagically created when I access "WebContext.Current.Authentication")... how can I override this and pass the right URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the ctor with URI do the following:

after creating the web context:

```
WebContext webContext = new WebContext();
webContext.Authentication = new FormsAuthentication();
this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(webContext);
```

set the AuthenticationDomain Context using the URI like this:

```
((WebAuthenticationService)WebContextBase.Current.Authentication).DomainContext = new AuthenticationContext(new Uri(uriPath));
```